# Converting a string with an array structure

Tags: php, laravel

I am saving several values in the database.
When I output, I get the string ["1"] or ["1", "2"].
How do I convert it to an array so that I can make a selection from the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value has been stored into the database as json string, simply decode the value

```
$check = '["1", "2"]';
$new = json_decode($check);
print_r($new);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use model can try this

```
protected $casts = [
    'your_db_field_name' => 'array' 
];
```

and your result try convert it to array.
But if you want save array in DB try use JSON format

[original material](https://laraveldaily.com/working-with-mysql-json-columns-in-laravel-custom-properties-example/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'one,two,three,four';
$count=substr_count($str, ",") +1;
echo $count;
// zero limit
for($i=0;$i<=$count;$i++)
{
$element[]=explode(',',$str,$i);
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($element[$count]);
?>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).